# How to run Gcloud datastore emulator in Travis-ci?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, travis-ci

I'm having some problems running Gcloud's Datastore emulator in Travis-ci.

Now running it like:

```
script:
  - export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
  - echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
  - curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
  - nohup gcloud beta emulators datastore start &
```

But this seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong with this setup, as you say it is 'less than ideal', which indicates that it works.

If you want the setup steps to be cleaner, you can install the `google-cloud-sdk` directly because it's [whitelisted by travis](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/blob/master/ubuntu-trusty#L1892):

```
dist: trusty
  apt:
    packages:
    - google-cloud-sdk
before_script: 
- gcloud beta emulators datastore start &
- $(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)
```